# $(window).height() inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Today I faced some really stranger bug. For example: my site opens in the iframe(this iframe automatically fit all document space, width and height) inside this frame I need to get value of `$(window).height();` and I get... Very big value(5000-10000px).

Demo link - http://bug-wheight.divshot.io/
Open this in your browser, then resize window one-two-times and look at counter. This value is not correct.

**Info:** bug detected in chrome, version 41.0.2272.118(mac). Safari on iOS 8.0.1 also returns very big values. Mozilla(ver. 35.0.1) returns small integers(is about 35px, what?). My screen size: 2560 x 1440.

**And question:** how I can get real window height value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add **Document type definition** in your html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

It will work fine.

Comment: This is correct. Without this doctype, your browser is running in "quirks" mode and jQuery cannot correctly calculate the height.